# 6 min 15 seconds to launch Firefox Profile using Selenium WebDriver? Is that normal?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

When I tried launching Selenium 3.0 using existing Firefox Profile it took 6 min 15 seconds for the profile to open. Now I understand Selenium has to copy profile to a temporary directory but I'm not using a Dell 316LT, launched in 1989. I running it on a PC with at least 16 GB of extra RAM + monster CPU.

Why does it take so long for Selenium to open Firefox? What can be done to expedite the process?

The fact that Selenium needs to copy profile to temporary location does not explain why it takes this long. No way. The size of the Firefox folder is approx. 420 MB. *It took me approx. 15 seconds to copy the entire profile folder to a new location.* **So why is Selenium so much slower?**

I'm using version 87 of Firefox and latest Geckdriver. Launching Selenium in Java.

Comment: How is your network bandwidth ?

Comment: @cruisepandey **very** fast. I'm using **top notch** hardware.

Comment: @cruisepandey you mean wireless network? why would network bandwidth play a role anyway?

Comment: Selenium makes a call to HTTP server to initialize and create profile so network is required

Comment: Even without Selenium Grid?